# How can I read, run a query from an SQL file using ibm_db in Node.js?

Tags: sql, node.js, db2

I am using Node.js and the [ibm_db](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db) package to access my DB2 database. I know how to run a text script, but I have a script in an SQL file and I don't know how to approach that.

ibm_db sample:

```
var ibmdb = require("ibm_db")
, cn = "DATABASE=database;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;"
;

ibmdb.open(cn, function (err, conn) {
if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

// we now have an open connection to the database, so lets get some data.
// Execute multiple query and get multiple result sets.
// In case of multiple resultset, query will return an array of result sets.
conn.query("select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1;select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1;" +
           "select 3 from sysibm.sysdummy1", function (err, rows) 
{
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(rows); // rows = [ [ { '1': 1 } ], [ { '1': 2 } ], [ { '1': 3 } ] ]
    }
});
});
```

In this case the query is performed with a string passed into `con.query(...)`

I have an SQL File (like `sample.sql`) that contains a few queries like:

```
select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1;
select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1;
select 3 from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

I need to `sample.sql` in Node and run the queries. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Provide a skeleton of what you want to do. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi @data_henrik, I updated the question. Please let me know if that is more useful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you mean how to read the file, turn the statements into queries to be executed? What happens with the results?

Comment: All of those. Do I just read the files using the File system and submit the queries? Or is there ibm_db functionality to consume an SQL file and be able to handle the script?

Comment: node-ibm_db is to interact with Db2, nothing more. Everything else is your job :)

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to verify that.